Uboot/Linux Kernel. Pure SD Boot
Having trouble booting linux from an SD card on a RK3566 Board
Here is my partition structure.

Part    Start LBA       End LBA         Name
        Attributes
        Type GUID
        Partition GUID
  1     0x00002000      0x00005fff      "uboot"
        attrs:  0x0000000000000000
        type:   0fc63daf-8483-4772-8e79-3d69d8477de4
        guid:   495cfe27-dcd2-42d0-b087-ce43753af54b
  2     0x00006000      0x00009fff      "misc"
        attrs:  0x0000000000000000
        type:   0fc63daf-8483-4772-8e79-3d69d8477de4
        guid:   d49f7e11-67c2-41b9-95e3-c2f2aec54b60
  3     0x0000a000      0x00135fff      "boot"
        attrs:  0x0000000000000000
        type:   ebd0a0a2-b9e5-4433-87c0-68b6b72699c7
        guid:   576e8ecc-f08e-44e1-af06-4a3844f487bf
  4     0x00136000      0x073ff7ff      "rootfs"
        attrs:  0x0000000000000000
        type:   0fc63daf-8483-4772-8e79-3d69d8477de4
        guid:   7698d2db-1576-4c94-8e60-07c8bb2a5d78

Here is boot
=> ls mmc 1:3
      140   uEnv.txt
   112974   rk3566-rock-3a.dtb
  4613819   initrd.gz
 23861256   Image
     1474   boot.scr


Running the following
setenv bootcmd "load mmc 1:2 ${kernel_addr_r} Image; load mmc 1:2 ${fdt_addr_r} rk3566-rock-3a.dtb; booti ${kernel_addr_r} - ${fdt_addr_r}"
setenv bootargs 'console=ttyS0,115200 root=/dev/mmcblk1p3 rootwait init=/bin/sh debug'

Gets stuck at Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk1p3.
MMC0 is the EMMC. i do not wish to boot from that, only SD card. If I set the same for mmcblk0p4 (emmc) it boots fine. So it looks like the SD is not mounting the correct partitions
Is there a change I need to make when compiling kernel (4.19) to allow mounting of the SD card partitions?
[    1.312995] mmcblk0: mmc0:0001 SLD64G 57.6 GiB
[    1.313811] mmcblk0boot0: mmc0:0001 SLD64G partition 1 4.00 MiB
[    1.314617] mmcblk0boot1: mmc0:0001 SLD64G partition 2 4.00 MiB
[    1.314894] mmcblk0rpmb: mmc0:0001 SLD64G partition 3 4.00 MiB, chardev (240:0)
[    1.332159] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: probing start
[    1.332649] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: Looking up venc-supply from device tree
[    1.332741] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: Linked as a consumer to regulator.10
[    1.332763] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: Failed to get leakage
[    1.332820] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: pvtm = 85400, from nvmem
[    1.332839] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: pvtm-volt-sel=1
[    1.333015] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: avs=0
[    1.333333] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: failed to find power_model node
[    1.333348] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: failed to initialize power model
[    1.333360] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: failed to get dynamic-coefficient
[    1.333740] mpp_rkvenc fdf40000.rkvenc: probing finish
[    1.334381] mali fde60000.gpu: Kernel DDK version g2p0-01eac0
[    1.334471] mali fde60000.gpu: Looking up mali-supply from device tree
[    1.334569] mali fde60000.gpu: Linked as a consumer to regulator.11
[    1.334584] mali fde60000.gpu: Looking up shadercores-supply from device tree
[    1.334601] mali fde60000.gpu: Looking up shadercores-supply property in node /gpu@fde60000 failed
[    1.334662] mali fde60000.gpu: Looking up mali-supply from device tree
[    1.334689] vdd_gpu: could not add device link fde60000.gpu err -17
[    1.334705] vdd_gpu: Failed to create debugfs directory
[    1.334720] mali fde60000.gpu: Looking up shadercores-supply from device tree
[    1.334735] mali fde60000.gpu: Looking up shadercores-supply property in node /gpu@fde60000 failed
[    1.334756] mali fde60000.gpu: dev_pm_opp_set_regulators: no regulator (shadercores) found: -19
[    1.334847] mali fde60000.gpu: leakage=7
[    1.334891] mali fde60000.gpu: pvtm = 85400, from nvmem
[    1.335296] mali fde60000.gpu: avs=0
[    1.335318] W : [File] : drivers/gpu/arm/bifrost/platform/rk/mali_kbase_config_rk.c; [Line] : 112; [Func] : kbase_platform_rk_init(); power-off-delay-ms not available.
[    1.335652] mali fde60000.gpu: GPU identified as 0x2 arch 7.4.0 r1p0 status 0
[    1.335738] mali fde60000.gpu: No memory group manager is configured
[    1.336149] mali fde60000.gpu: l=-2147483648 h=2147483647 hyst=0 l_limit=0 h_limit=0 h_table=0
[    1.336796] mali fde60000.gpu: Probed as mali0
[    1.337264] input: adc-keys as /devices/platform/adc-keys/input/input1
[    1.343190] asoc-simple-card rk809-sound: rk817-hifi <-> fe410000.i2s mapping ok
[    1.345071] rk_iommu fde4b000.iommu: ignoring dependency for device, assuming no driver
[    1.345393]  mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3 p4
[    1.346212] rockchip-pm-domain fdd90000.power-management:power-controller: Looking up pd_pipe-supply from device tree
[    1.346259] rockchip-pm-domain fdd90000.power-management:power-controller: Looking up pd_pipe-supply property in node /power-management@fdd90000/power-controller failed
[    1.346371] rockchip-pm-domain fdd90000.power-management:power-controller: Looking up pd_vi-supply from device tree
[    1.346399] rockchip-pm-domain fdd90000.power-management:power-controller: Looking up pd_vi-supply property in node /power-management@fdd90000/power-controller failed
[    1.347754] RKNPU fde40000.npu: ignoring dependency for device, assuming no driver
[    1.348127] RKNPU fde40000.npu: ignoring dependency for device, assuming no driver
[    1.348584] cfg80211: Loading compiled-in X.509 certificates for regulatory database
[    1.349979] cfg80211: Loaded X.509 cert 'sforshee: 00b28ddf47aef9cea7'
[    1.350077] platform regulatory.0: Direct firmware load for regulatory.db failed with error -2
[    1.350093] cfg80211: failed to load regulatory.db
[    1.350936] rockchip-pm-domain fdd90000.power-management:power-controller: Looking up pd_vo-supply from device tree
[    1.350975] rockchip-pm-domain fdd90000.power-management:power-controller: Looking up pd_vo-supply property in node /power-management@fdd90000/power-controller failed
[    1.351805] I : [File] : drivers/gpu/arm/mali400/mali/linux/mali_kernel_linux.c; [Line] : 417; [Func] : mali_module_init(); svn_rev_string_from_arm of this mali_ko is '', rk_ko_ver is '5', built at '19:06:06', on 'May 21 2024'.
[    1.352092] Mali:
[    1.352093] Mali device driver loaded
[    1.352218] ALSA device list:
[    1.352228]   #0: rockchip,rk809-codec
[    1.352532] Waiting for root device /dev/mmcblk1p3...
[    1.367996] mmc_host mmc2: Bus speed (slot 0) = 25000000Hz (slot req 25000000Hz, actual 25000000HZ div = 0)
[    1.370418] mmc2: new high speed SDIO card at address 0001
[    1.405894] vendor storage:20190527 ret = 0
[    1.438441] devfreq fde60000.gpu: Couldn't update frequency transition information.
[   32.054278] vcc5v0_otg: disabling



That snippet of the boot log only shows that the mmcblk0 device (i.e. the eMMC) is recognized and installed. Is any mention of the mmcblk1 device (i.e. the SD card) actually missing from the (entire) boot log? Is the mmcblk1 device (i.e. the SD card) supposed to be installed, i.e. is  the mmcblk1 device specified in your Device Tree, aka the board's configuration?

Appreciate your response. No mention of mmcblk1 in the logs anywhere. Although u-boot sees everything fine. It just appears the kernel does not.
This device does not boot from SD natively. It’s a consumer device designed to be booted from EMMC and that’s it. So this is a hack of some sorts. Checking the dtb shows SD support though which is why I assume I can boot u-boot from the SD card.

"No mention of mmcblk1" - Then your kernel is not configured to use the SD card socket connected to the SD/MMC controller. "Checking the dtb shows SD support though which is why I assume I can boot u-boot ..." - Huh? What "dtb" are you looking at? How did you "check" a "dtb"? Each boot stage has its own, possibly unique, perspective of the board configuration. You need to review the Device Tree that is passed to the kernel. What U-Boot (or earlier boot stages) can access does not automatically transfer to the kernel.

You can decompile dtbs and check its structure. It’s pretty easy. There are entries for the SD card and what is supported. Guess we can all learn something here.
The rest of your comment confirms what I suspected. So thanks for that. I’ll dig in further for  kernel configuration

"Guess we can all learn something here" - I learned that you expect others to read your mind when you write ambiguous statements.

If you ask me, your kernel is already booted from the SD card into the initramsfs inside initrd file, loaded from the SD card. What I think you want to do is switchroot to /dev/mmcblk1p4 where the rootfs is?
You need the kernel to have sdhci* kernel modules. Either built-in or in the initrd. And the kernel needs to be aware of the SD card, in my case we have that in acpi, in your case in dt I guess. The kernel needs to be able to detect the card inserted, I remember we had the switch polarity inverted at some point, then still it doesn't work. And then you need the kernel to have the right file system modules built-in or in the initrd. And then mounted. And then switchroot.
What I did for Intel Edison is first make sure the kernel can actually detect the SD card and read from the file system. That by booting from the eMMC and trying to read the SD card.
Then when that works, get the right stuff into the initrd. I my case I have the init script in the initrd drop to a console after a certain amount of time "Waiting for root device ...". Then you can investigate what's going on there (missing kernel modules?).
What I have in the log on Intel Edison:
root@yuna:~# journalctl -b -0 -k | grep mmc
May 21 22:52:38 edison kernel: Command line: quiet root=/dev/mmcblk0p8 rootflags=subvol=@,compress=lzo rootfstype=btrfs console=ttyS2,115200n8 earlyprintk=ttyS2,115200n8,keep loglevel=4 systemd.unit=multi-user.target
May 21 22:52:38 edison kernel: Kernel command line: quiet root=/dev/mmcblk0p8 rootflags=subvol=@,compress=lzo rootfstype=btrfs console=ttyS2,115200n8 earlyprintk=ttyS2,115200n8,keep loglevel=4 systemd.unit=multi-user.target
May 21 22:52:38 edison kernel: mmc0: SDHCI controller on PCI [0000:00:01.0] using ADMA
May 21 22:52:38 edison kernel: mmc2: SDHCI controller on PCI [0000:00:01.3] using ADMA
May 21 22:52:38 edison kernel: mmc1: SDHCI controller on PCI [0000:00:01.2] using ADMA
May 21 22:52:38 edison kernel: mmc1: new high speed SDXC card at address 59b4
May 21 22:52:38 edison kernel: mmc0: new DDR MMC card at address 0001
May 21 22:52:38 edison kernel: mmc2: new ultra high speed DDR50 SDIO card at address 0001
May 21 22:52:39 edison kernel: mmcblk1: mmc1:59b4 SD64G 59.4 GiB
May 21 22:52:39 edison kernel:  mmcblk0: p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8


Yocto recipe for initrd: https://github.com/edison-fw/meta-intel-edison/blob/master/meta-intel-edison-distro/recipes-core/images/edison-image-minimal.bb
Init script: https://github.com/edison-fw/meta-intel-edison/blob/master/meta-intel-edison-distro/recipes-core/initrdscripts/initramfs-framework/init
Manifest of the initrd (but there are also drivers built-in the kernel that are not listed here): https://edison-fw.github.io/meta-intel-edison/core-image-minimal-initramfs-edison.manifest


Nice. Thanks for the tip. I'll dig into this futher. I'm fairly sure i did mmcblk1p4 i think that's just a typo, i've tried countless env options so may have pasted the wrong one in here.
